# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Unable to uninstall

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

This happens if I try to uninstall it or even repair it. The setup stops working at the end.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Microsoft Windows Installer Cleanup Utility from, for example, [MajorGeeks.com](http://majorgeeks.com/download.php?det=4459)

Run it, find all records Microsoft SQL Server... and remove it. Clear registry from trash records, for example, by [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/standard). Then install SQL Server again and remove it from add/remove in control panel.

Comment: I'm against using a registry cleaner in principle, but the rest of your advice might work. Bear in mind that the Cleanup Utility is no longer supported by Microsoft because it is older technology.

Comment: "Bear in mind that the Cleanup Utility is no longer supported by Microsoft because it is older technology" - but it work! And Ccleaner is harmless, imho.